# C# architectural guideline - Batch job

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

We have healthcare office in 800 locations and
Right now we have web application and each facility manager click web application button triggers api which does complex backend operation and getting time out some times. to avoid that, i am planning to do this on the c# console application job.

I have a c# console application created and can be scheduled on task scheduler. have 5 servers to deploy this. this batch job calls multiple procs and its does complex operations. so one facility will take 3-4 minutes to finish operation. I cannot do sequential operation like one facility at a time. I need to run this for 800 facilities at a time. This has to happen 5pm everyday for each facility. What is the best way to achieve this scenario from architectural perspective.

Comment: Well i dont think you will be able to run 800 offices at once. you might get away with a few offices at a time in batches. There is another factory to take into account when designing the concurrency strategy which is the database, you say it has to run stored procedures which might or might not be able to be run concurrently imagine that it might affect financial information and that each office has to be a transaction for example.   So to give you a better opinion we need more details.

Comment: there's not really any details about your setup.

Comment: Without any further information: Have you looked at Hangfire? It's a (background) job management library that can also scale across multiple servers...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and i will look into Hangfire.